# Find/generate standard PPD file when installing a printer from command line

Tags: printing

I need to install a network printer using the command line. This is for automated installation and reconfiguration with CFEngine on dozens of PCs.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit. Printer model: HP LaserJet P3010.

Using the GUI, with "system-config-printer", I can set up my printer and print. The printer model is known by CUPS, no need to install a driver manually.

Ideally, I would like to use a command such as this:

```
lpadmin -p 'myprintername' -v 'smb://myserver/myprinter' -m 'HP LaserJet P3010 Series Postscript (recommended)' -P '...../hp-laserjet_p3010_series-ps.ppd' -L 'Printer location' -o 'HPOption_Duplexer/Duplex Unit=True' -E
```

The problem is that the "...../hp-laserjet_p3010_series-ps.ppd" PPD file is a fiction - There are no PPD files as such installed on Ubuntu.

From what I understand, CUPS has its own database from which it can generate the PPD files. The "system-config-printer" command somehow generates a PPD file in "/etc/cups/ppd" for the printer. Or maybe it retrieves the data from the Samba/CUPS server.

How can I install this printer from the command line ?
Is it possible to generate the PPD file the same way as "system-config-printer" does, but using the command line ?

Comment: complete guess, but there are some python scripts provided by the `python-cupshelpers` package - maybe that's where the magic happens?

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered at:

[How to add printer to my server and share it with no GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765376/how-to-add-printer-to-my-server-and-share-it-with-no-gui)

You can use

```
lpinfo -m
```

To get a list of the all the ppd files available.

```
$ lpinfo --make-and-model "HP LaserJet P3010" -m
drv:///hpijs.drv/hp-laserjet_p3010_series-hpijs-pcl3.ppd HP LaserJet p3010 Series hpijs pcl3, 3.16.11
drv:///hpcups.drv/hp-laserjet_p3010_series-pcl3.ppd HP LaserJet p3010 Series pcl3, hpcups 3.16.11
postscript-hp:0/ppd/hplip/HP/hp-laserjet_p3010_series-ps.ppd HP LaserJet P3010 Series Postscript (recommended)
postscript-hp:1/ppd/hplip/HP/hp-laserjet_p3010_series-ps.ppd HP LaserJet P3010 Series Postscript (recommended)
postscript-hp:2/ppd/hplip/HP/hp-laserjet_p3010_series-ps.ppd HP LaserJet P3010 Series Postscript (recommended)
```

You can then directly reference the ppd in the list returned for your lpadmin command

```
lpadmin -p 'myprintername' -v 'smb://myserver/myprinter' -m 'postscript-hp:0/ppd/hplip/HP/hp-laserjet_p3010_series-ps.ppd' -L 'Printer location' -o 'HPOption_Duplexer/Duplex Unit=True' -E
```