# How to add printer to my server and share it with no GUI?

Tags: networking, server, printing

I have Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS installed on my server. I need to add a printer to my server which is connected through parallel port and share it via my local network, so that other devices on the subnet could see the shared printer and send their print jobs to it. My server has no GUI and I need the commands needed to be entered in command line to add and share the printer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found:

```
lpadmin -p HP1200 -m foomatic-db-compressed-ppds:0/ppd/foomatic-ppd/HP-LaserJet_1200-ljet4.ppd -v parallel:/dev/lp0 -E
```

- Instead of **HP1200** you may use your own printer name such as *myprinter*
- To find proper ppd file for your printer model (which must be mentioned after `-m` option) use `lpinfo -m`
- And you may use another *device-uri* after `-v` option. Use the `-v` option with the `lpinfo` command to get a list of supported device URIs and schemes.

After above command, to check if the printer is added properly use `lpstat -t`. It displays in my case:

```
scheduler is running
system default destination: HP1200
device for HP1200: parallel:/dev/lp0
HP1200 accepting requests since Sun 01 May 2016 12:35:40 AM JST
printer HP1200 is idle.  enabled since Sun 01 May 2016 12:35:40 AM JST
```

To see default options for your printer use `lpoptions -l`, and to change them use for example:

```
lpoptions -p HP1200 -o PageSize=A4 -o tonerdensity=5
```

To set this printer as defalt printer, use `lpadmin` with `-d` option:

```
lpadmin -d HP1200
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control CUPS (Common Unix Printing System) from any computer on your LAN. Point a browser at `http://server:631`. CUPS will let you add the new printer, pick a driver, setup a print queue, and share it on the LAN.

Comment: My server IP address is `192.168.0.100` and if I enter this address in address bar of another machine (which has GUI) on the network, It displayes: "**It Works!**", but `192.168.0.100:631` does not works, browser shows: _unable to connect_ page